# Helix Toolkit Color Bleeding on Zoom

Tags: c#, helix-3d-toolkit

Using the Helix Toolkit I can see colors bleeding through when zooming.  The closer I zoom the better it gets, zooming out make it worse.  Is this a problem with the HelixViewport3D or my Obj model?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with model interference. Either in (A) the CAD software as modelled features or as (B) exported mesh or mesh duplication or mesh tolerances tolerances/interference between vertices.

Suggest first investigating the model/assembly to see if there is any interference (most parametric software has an interference check as well as settings to change the part accuracy which will influence Tessellation later.

Second if part/assembly is modelled correctly with no interference and part(mesh) tolerances are apt.. Export with if options allow a reduced 'cord height' for smoother features.

Third, taking the model into Blender for example and merging vertices. If you use Sketchup or another surface modeller or even a parametric CAD software but utilising surface models these may have somehow been occupying the same vertex values.

Hope this helps, but normally it is modelling that causes the issue that has a downstream impact.

Comment: Removing NearPlaneDistance="0.001" from the PerspectiveCamera seems to have fixed it.  This may relate to https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/issues/1232

Comment: Hi Rob, tried this unfortunately didn't do the trick. Suspect there is a bigger issue with this as I have tried breaking it down to switching out models from different applications and checking naming inside and out of all files.  Just wish the Helix tool-kit was a bit better documented. If I find an answer to this I am going to update the documentation on this.